# Using an identical interface in different versions of a 3rd party interop library

Tags: c#, .net, interop, dry, autocad

We have an app where we switch between different versions of a 3rd party interop library (AutoCad). The subset of the interop API we use is the same across all versions of the interop library.

What would be the most effective way to reference different versions of the library while reusing the client code?

One approach is to use reflection: define a wrapper type for each of the used interop interfaces and use reflection inside the wrappers to load the interop type from the specified version of the interop assembly and just proxy every call to the interop object. This approach looks wasteful to me when all the interfaces in the used subset are exactly the same across all versions of the interop.

Other approach would be to reference different interop assemblies in different configurations of the project. With the identical interfaces across interop assemblies this should allow to compile different versions of the client assembly for each version of the interop assembly. One thing I'm not sure how to implement in this approach is configuring the project so that it builds all the versions of the client assembly at the same time to include them all in a single distribution.

It should be possible to employ code gen here as well, but I'm not sure how difficult it could be.

How would you solve this kind of problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Use late binding.  Only easy to do in C# with the *dynamic* keyword.

Answer (score 2):

For versions less than AutoCAD 2013, you can actually get away with only referencing one interop assembly and shipping the same output assembly. The AutoCAD interop assemblies are not strong-signed and do not require a particular version. There are a few API's that have changed over the years which can either be solved by reflection or "sub" assemblies that reference the correct interop assemblies.

AutoCAD 2013 changed the interop libraries significantly. You can either reference different assemblies per configuration which would require manually editing the project file as you can't do it through the gui, or setup two different projects, which can be in the same solution, which reference the different assemblies. You can link the files from one project to the other so that you don't duplicate files.

I've used both techniques and which works better depends on the situation.

Comment: Hm, we're using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop and Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common, these are strongly named, reside in GAC(autocad installer puts them there) and have different version numbers for different versions of AutoCAD . Are there non-strongly named versions of these?

Comment: Ah, you're using the COM Interop libraries. I suspect you've picked those thru the COM tab of the add reference dialog. The ObjectARX sdk from them include COM libraries that I don't believe are strong signed. Have you tried using the pure .net assemblies or are you doing things that require the COM stuff?

Comment: I'm not sure if we need any of the COM stuff, its kind of a legacy project so I don't think that switching interops is an option at this point. I think we'd go with the option with different projects referencing the same source files if we don't find a way to make a single project to produce several assemblies for different versions of the interop (should be possible with a custom MS build script).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a modified version of your first approach. Define your own interface, so you can always reference that. Have a single implementation which loads the library passed in from the constructor. The constructor instantiates an instance of the interop assembly object via reflection, and saves it in a private member field. The methods for the implementation of the object call the methods of the object using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you call only a handful interfaces of AutoCAD Interop, using reflection or later binding may be a good option. In this way, you don't need to worry about different AutoCAD versions, different COM references or such since you mentioned all the interfaces are the same across all the AutoCAD versions of your concern.

If there are a lot of COM calls, you may find the reflection or COM later binding are pretty tedious and error prone. In this way, creating different builds for different AutoCAD seems not a bad idea though those COM interfaces may be just the same. In terms of creating all these builds at the same time, some different project configurations could be generated into the single solution, or better some MAKE files are used.